# Firebase function to check unread message count

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Here's the sample collection in a Firebase Firestore database:

```
rooms
|-room_1
  |-messages
    |-msg_1
    |-msg_2
```

In the example above, `rooms` and `messages` are collections. Each room has a string array property called `userAccess`. This property holds list of user uuids that has access to this room. Each message has a `seenBy` string array property that holds a list of users' uuids that have seen this message.

The challenge is, after each message creation, to wait for 3 minutes and determine the list of users who have access to this room and have not seen this message. The end goal is to determine the sum of unread messages for each user and send a request to another server.

**What I tried:**
I tried to do a cronjob to check all users in every x minutes but as the count of users grows, the complexity of the function also grows and the function fails more often. So the cronjob option is not the way to go.

What would be the proper way this kind of task in Firebase Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

How many users do you expect those arrays to contain?

**10?** Then your cloud function will easily resolve your problem using [except](https://www.npmjs.com/package/except)

```
var unseen = except(room.userAccess, message.seenBy);
```

**10 millions?** Hard to handle without getting a timeout, so I guess the architecture needs to be redesigned